# SQL column exists in table but not in INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql-server

I have a table created in sql. but in my application I am using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to perform some tasks, I was surprised it wasn't synchronized with my table definition, that is

**Code**:

```
SELECT  SatComRatingTableID         -- This is working
FROM    dbo.tblSatComRatingTable


SELECT  f.field ,
        c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM    dbo.wiztbl_Fields f
        LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.COLUMN_NAME = f.Field
                                                  AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'tblSatComBillingPackage'
WHERE   f.DataObjectID = 2717
        AND COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

the second query returns:

```
SatComRatingTableID NULL
```

What is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**:

NB: the tblSatComBillingPackage contains a FK field SatComRatingTableID. I am using that field to get information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA...

Comment: Because you're querying against the wrong table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the wrong table, and seem to be filtering the results to preclude success:

```
SELECT  SatComRatingTableID
FROM    dbo.tblSatComRatingTable --<--This


SELECT  f.field ,
        c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM    dbo.wiztbl_Fields f
        LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.COLUMN_NAME = f.Field
             AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'tblSatComBillingPackage'  --<-- Does't match this
WHERE   f.DataObjectID = 2717
        AND COLUMN_NAME IS NULL --<-- And this seems wrong also
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that the SatcomBillingPackage has a SatComRatingTableID FK and I am using that value to get related information from Information_Schema...

Comment: @Boomer - nope, you've lost me there. You've got a query at the top against `tblSatComRatingTable`. You're then querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for a *different* table (`tblSatComBillingPackage`). And you have a `WHERE` clause filter than seems intended to filter out any successful matches.

Comment: Sorry and thanx for u support. table BillingPackage contains a field named tblSatComRatingTableID, when I try to get that column from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, it gives me NULL.

Comment: @Boomer - It can't *not* give you a NULL result when you have `COLUMN_NAME is NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That is the problem. The second query is returning a NULL on column `SatComRatingTableID`, as I wrote in my question.